# How to query nested arrays in mongodb from command line

Tags: mongodb

I have some data structured like this in a mongo collection:

```
{ "list" : [ { "update_time" : NumberLong(1426690563), "provider" : NumberLong(4) } ] }
```

What I would like to do is query for all of the entries where the `list` includes a `provider` value of 4.

If it helps, all of the `list` arrays contain only one element.

What I am trying right now is this:

```
db.collection.find(
    {
      list: {
              provider: 4
            }
    }
)
```

This does not work though, and always returns an empty set

Comment: This is the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **[dot notation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-documents/#match-a-field-without-specifying-array-index)** i.e. concatenate the name of the field that contains the array, with a dot (.) and the name of the field in the embedded document and use that as your query:

```
db.collection.find({"list.provider": 4})
```

You can also use the **[$elemMatch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-documents/#id3)** operator to specify multiple criteria on an array of embedded documents such that at least one embedded document satisfies all the specified criteria:

```
db.collection.find({
    list: {
        $elemMatch: {
            provider: 4
        }
    }
})
```